# Are collars really downside protection?

Tags: options, option-strategies

I see collars often mentioned as downside protection for a stock you own. My question is: How?

Let's say you bought at stock at 45 and it is now 50. You can collar the 45 cost basis (one strike above 45 and one below). This is considered downside protection.

Now the stock moves down to 45. Then continues to 39, 37, 35. The collar expires. The stock is now 34. Where's the downside protection? Even if the collar is still on, where is the downside protection?

Answer (score 1):

The stock is currently at 50.

Write a covered call at a strike price of 55. Use the money received from the covered-call-write to buy a put at a strike price of 45.

The position keeps the upside to a stock price of 55 but has no more upside beyond 55. Or the position will have gain on the put at anything less than 45 which is the downside protection.

Options are for a limited amount of time.

Comment: What happens when the options expire and the price is at 44?

Comment: @4thSpace: In-the-money options in most exchanges are automatically exercised right before expiration.  Ask your broker if this is true for you.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Doesn't the 50 call and the 45 put cancel each other out at expiration? You're then left holding the bag (exposed) with an upside down 50 cost basis stock while the price is at 37.

Comment: @4thSpace: What?  No, the 50 (or 55, according to the answer) call is worthless, no one will exercise it against you at 50 when they can buy on the market for 37.

Comment: The short call and long put only balance each other at the stock price when you bought the collar.  If the stock price goes down, the put becomes worth more and the call becomes less of a liability.  If the stock price goes up, the call becomes a greater liability and the put devalues.  But your stock value went up.  The collar has the effect of reducing your exposure to the market.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I get that. So the collar dissolves at expiration. Why are you talking about exercising an option that isn't there?

Comment: ALL in-the-money options are automatically exercised by the OCC at expiration and is called Exercise by Exception unless If you are long the option and  you designate to the OCC via your broker that your options are not auto exercised at expiration.  This would make sense if they are ITM by pennies and your commission to close the position exceeds the ITM amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a put option, you can choose to sell at its strike price (this is called *exercising the option*) rather than the stock's market price.

Comment: Exercising the long put to close the equity position is the better choice (1) if the put's bid is less than its intrinsic value (avoids the haircut), (2) it avoids leg out risk, (3) if your broker does not charge for assignment and exercise,

Comment: Can you show an example of this? You can use ~$7 for commission.

Comment: You own a $150 put expiring in an hour and the stock is $145 ($5 intrinsic value).  Quote is $4.75 x $5.25 so that's a 25 cent haircut ($25) at the market.   Putting in a higher bid has gotten you nowhere because there is no incentive for the market maker to do so. Short the stock (first) and then exercise the put.  If you pay for assignment and exercise (A&E), that's $14 in commissions to save $11.  I pay $1 for the short with free A&E so it's $1 to save $25.  Heck, I'll do it for a nickel.  20 contracts saves $80.

Comment: I'm talking about a $600 drawdown and you're worried about saving $11. I think you're in the wrong trade. You can't short a stock you own. Also, the OP doesn't own a $150 put. Again, wrong trade. You say nothing about where you bought, which strikes, etc. Too vague.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I mucked this one up. That explanation was applicable for closing an unencumbered long ITM put or call  where  the bid is less than the intrinsic value. our situation is similar when you add the long equity to the position. If stock bot @ $45 and assuming it was a no cost collar then put cost was zero (ignoring commissions).  If stock at $40 and  put is $4.75 x $5.25 then if you sell both, that's a 25 cent haircut plus $14 in commissions.  Exercise put and you avoid the haircut and pay same commish assuming exercise and sell commish are same). If free A&E, no closing cost.

Comment: I vote this question down since it is too vague.

Comment: Sorry - above I mean "answer", not question.

Comment: I vote it up because it is a statement of fact.    You can exercise a long option rather than closing two individual positions.  Beyond that, (1) it's more expedient to close two positions in one order (a synthetic call position) and that avoids leg out risk and (2) some brokers charge less (or even nothing) for assignment exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the protection?

- If you buy a stock for $50 and it drops to $20 by expiration, the loss is 30 points.
- If you buy a stock for $50 and you execute  a 45p/55c no cost long stock collar, the loss is only 5 points at expiration.

If you want more  protection or a higher reward potential, you can shift the risk graph by selecting strikes that are not equidistant away from share price.  This will result in some amount of debit to put on the collar.

Prior to expiration, as the underlying drops, the put increases in price and the call decreases in price.  As a hypothetical example, if these were 30 IV options and the stock dropped immediately, the net loss might be only 3 points at $45.  The higher the IV, the less the loss would be.  The closer you are to expiration, the lower this mitigating factor would be.

If the underlying collapses below the long put strike and IF you still want to own the underlying, you could  roll the options down,  lowering your cost basis.  This will add more potential loss but will lower your upside break even price.

Note that long collared stock is synthetically equivalent to a vertical call spread so if opening all 3 legs simultaneously, consider the 2 legged critter to potentially reduce commissions and B/A damage.

Comment: And one day after expiration the loss is? If the stock is at 44, the loss is $600 per 100 shares held. What good did the collar the do?

Comment: @4thSpace - (1) What good did the collar the do? The collar cost you nothing.  It protected you from loss below the price of $45.   (2) Try again. At expiry, what's the $$5 call worth and what's the $45  put worth?

Comment: At expiry, the spread (collar) will be worth nothing. Now you are exposed to 44 and -$600 per 100 shares held. It works while the collar is on, but once it expires, too bad.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  It was meant to read: At expiry, what's the $55 call worth and what's the $45 put worth?

Comment: You question/complaint  is unclear.  If the stock is $44 at expiration then the put saved you $100.  If the stock is $44 after expiration, then it's a silly question because options are for a limited time.  Why in the world would you expect an expired option to protect you for subsequent price change?  At expiration of the initial collar, if you want ongoing protection, add another no/low cost collar to move the protection forward in time.  If your complaint is that you lost $5 from the drop from $50 to $45, that's not the fault of the options.  That was just a poor investment choice.

Comment: @4thSpace: *after* expiration, the options are worth nothing, but *at* expiration, in your example where the stock price is at 37, the $45 put is worth 800.  It gets automatically exercised, taking you out of the stock at a $0 capital loss (500 down from its high), and you don't suffer the further decline because you no longer have a position.  Of course, you're out several commissions (buying the stock, buying the collar, exercising the put, selling the stock at the put strike)

Comment: @BenVoigt: What about the 50 call that was sold to open the collar? Are you saying just buy the 45 put instead of creating a collar?

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about the parameters of the collar -the original question mention "You can collar the 45 cost basis (one strike above 45 and one below).  My answer and the one from "S Spring"  provided an example using a short $55 call for the collar.  Now you're asking about a $50 call.  If you instead you initially  put on a $50c/$45p collar when the stock was $50, you received a decent credit for the it  and your loss at $45 would be less than $5.  You might want to regroup on this one and get everyone on the same page.

Comment: The question was for @BenVoigt. 50 call or 55 call doesn't matter. I'm asking if he is saying the call even exist. Buying only a protective put is a different strategy. The whole allow the put to be assigned business can't happen with a collar (unless you close out the call for a loss, which no one has mentioned). Either way, people are stating only half of their thoughts, which is vague and hence all the follow up questions to clarify.

Comment: @4thSpace: If the price of the stock drops, you'll close out a call for a gain.  You sold it out of the money, worth X.  Now it is even further out of the money, worth Y so you buy it back to close for a profit of (X-Y).  Why do you think the put can't be exercised?  The collar as a whole is in the money in your example.

Comment: @4thSpace - This is just more confusion.  The call can only increase in value in 2 ways: Share price increases and/or implied volatility expands. So there is no "close out the call for a loss" and need not be mentioned since all along you have been talking about share price dropping.  So as you said, "50 call or 55 call doesn't matter". Leave it out of the discussion.  You also need to understand the difference between assignment and exercise.  Since you are long the put, you can exercise it.  There is no "allow the put to be assigned business" in a long stock collar..